# What does `morgan` module have to do with express apps?

Tags: node.js, express

In an express tutorial, the author was using the `npm module morgan`. What can morgan do for an express app? Could anyone help me understand this?

Got this by googling, but I do not understand anything here:

```
var express = require('express')
var morgan  = require('morgan')

var app = express()
app.use(morgan('combined'))
morgan('combined')

morgan(':remote-addr :method :url')

morgan(function (tokens, req, res) {
  return req.method + ' ' + req.url
})
```

Comment: `morgan` is a logger https://www.npmjs.org/package/morgan. When in doubt go to the npm site.

Comment: the question is not just a doubt, I am looking for some meaningful example to understand properly.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Morgan is used for logging request details. However, the snippet in your question doesn't make sense because it's not actually a single coherent snippet top to bottom. It is a series of examples of the various types of options you can pass to morgan. In a real program, you would only need one of them. For example:

```
var express = require('express')
var morgan  = require('morgan')

var app = express()
//This tells express to log via morgan
//and morgan to log in the "combined" pre-defined format
app.use(morgan('combined'))
//That's it. Everything in your snippet after this are just
//other variations your might want to use
```

Comment: Sorry i didn't understood the "combined" can you explain it please?

Comment: Morgan supports a handful of pre-defined logged formats with well-know names/structures. combined, common, dev, short, tiny. That string is telling morgan which log format you'd like it to use. https://www.npmjs.com/package/morgan#predefined-formats

Comment: @RotimiBest By default the logs write to standard out (the normal console output of your program). You can also pass configuration options if you want to write to a particular file on the filesystem.

Answer (score 32):

Morgan is basically a logger, on any requests being made,it generates logs automatically.

Comment: Maybe a dumb question but where are the logs stored, in a file or std.out?

Comment: @RotimiBest the module by default writes to the std out (console output). However, it can be easily configured to write these logs to a custom file on the file system.

Answer (score 7):

**Morgan:** is another HTTP request logger middleware for Node.js. It simplifies the process of logging requests to your application. You might think of Morgan as a helper that collects logs from your server, such as your request logs. It saves developers time because they don’t have to manually create common logs. It standardizes and automatically creates request logs.

Morgan can operate standalone, but commonly it’s used in combination with Winston. Winston is able to transport logs to an external location, or query them when analyzing a problem.

Comment: can you give a  example for using morgan, i am not getting you.

Answer (score 3):

Morgan is a popular HTTP request middleware logger for Node.js and basically used as a logger. It can be used with node js' winston package to consolidate HTTP request data logs with other information.

Answer (score 1):

morgan is a Node.js and Express middleware to log HTTP requests and errors, and simplifies the process.

setting up Morgan with express

```bash
npm install morgan
```

Now, you have added morgan with your project and it's time to setting up with express server.
At `index.js` file :

```js
const express = require('express'); //importing express
const morgan = require('morgan'); //importing morgan

const app = express(); //creating server using express

//using morgan for HTTP request logger 

app.use(morgan("tiny"));


//listening for http request at port 3000
app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.debug('App listening on :3000');
});
```

`Morgan notifies on the terminal which request comes at the server and how many times it takes to send the response back.`